# resizable for JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is there a "JQuery UI"-like **resizable** option available for JQuery Mobile? The reason I'm looking for this is because I can't get a resizable to respond to touch event (e.g. on Ipad), not even with touch-punch.

Comment: what do you want to resize? Because good old responsive CSS is doing just fine for me.

Comment: I have a split pane view.  One pane on top, one pane at the bottom, with a the resizer handle as the divider between the two. Currently I am using JQuery UI to resize the panes, i.e. as the height of the top pane increases, the height of the bottom pane decreases, and vice versa.

Answer (score -1):

You can also look at [jquery-resizable](https://github.com/RickStrahl/jquery-resizable), which is a standalone component. It has mobile support, although that is not specific to jquery mobile. Further details are in [[this blog post]](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Dec/21/A-small-jQuery-Resizable-Plugin).